# Size option not showing on product view page for configurable product in Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-swatches

**Color Options showing** but **size option not showing** also all setting in admin is correct

When i click on add to cart button it's show size required field but not size options are there

[image]

I checked in variations products have color and size options.
[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: did you get any solution ? I have the same problem.

Comment: I used a third-party module to import products and other data. I reimport it then it was solved.
I think it was data save entry issue in DB.